# How can I rename the boot menu entries of the Windows Boot Manager?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-11, bootloader, boot-manager

In my Windows 11 (2x) dual-boot setup, I have two boot menu entries with the exact same name `Windows 11`. To distinguish them, Windows adds the volume number to it, but I would like to have an even more obvious distinction between both entries.

How can I rename them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bcdedit` to rename the boot menu entries. Use just `bcdedit` first to list all entries:

```
bcdedit
```

The "description" line represents the text that is shown in the boot menu. To modify it, use the value of the "identifier" line (including curly braces) to reference it:

```
bcdedit /set '{current}' description 'Windows 11 with my custom text'
```